# Firefox not getting FullScreen using userChrome.css file

Tags: css, xml, ubuntu, user-interface, firefox

[image: ![Firefox screenshot]

1) Above attached is my Firefox screenshot. I have modified my userchrome.css file to get rid of the tabs but now Firefox has a big empty gap at the bottom. I am unable to get rid of it. I tried everything.

2) Also, how do I shrink my navigation bar to the right so that my tree Style tab occupies the whole left side.

Here is what I have tried so far:

> #main-window[sizemode="maximized"] #titlebar {margin-bottom: -34px !important; }
>
> #main-window[sizemode="maximized"] #nav-bar {margin-right: 138px; }

The -34px worked in expanding my main window but without the outside frame so it ended up hiding the bottom part of the window. I think there should be another "Frame-window" or something?

I am really surprised that no one has asked a question like this; I mean almost anyone who uses Tree Style Tabs add-on is bound to face this issue and that addon has like more than a million users.

Comment: Hi, fiddled with Thunderbird in this manner the other day, so I can confirm your endeavor can be tricky and non- intuitive surprises can come up. However, FF has quite a bit of addons dealing with tabs, maybe you can investigate those, see how it's done and draw some inspiration from them? Regards, M.

Comment: @Micha, well, do you know of any frame that covers the main_window? because of which even though my main-window expanded, it just went underneath the outside frame of firefox?
all I am looking for is the name of the outermost frame of firefox. :))

Comment: Hi, we need to be careful WHICH frame or window we mean. As far as I know is #main-window the outer-most window in FF and TB, and your -34px experiment brought another question to my attention: could it be that there is a unwanted or weird interaction with the frame the operating system (or window system) is adding to the "raw" window of an application? Do you know what I mean? Regards, M.

Comment: @Micha, Could be. I don't know but I think it's more likely firefox's doing but I can't be sure.
But If what you said about the main_window is true then I think it might be that firefox is counting the tabs in the maximum window size even after they are no longer visible? I don't know for sure.

Comment: @Micha, You seem like a person who has much more experience dealing with CSS than I do so would really owe you big time if you also tried experimenting with your firefox's userchrome.css file and saw for yourself as well?
I mean, I doubt you like seeing those Tabs uptop when you have or you can have Tree Style Tabs.? :))


I can also give you my userChrome file if you wanna and we can figure this issue out together? what do you say?

Comment: Ah, well I certainly could try. Could you post the file(s) here, or prepare something more complete at github for me to download / clone and exactly try out for myself. Also add a very brief README.md of what you did, expected and got?

Comment: https://github.com/LucKy-4U/Firefox-Chrome-Folder

Please let me know if  you need anymore details or anything else. :))
THANKSSSS A LOOTTT for helping me out, will owe you one. :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to Micha, I was able to partially solve the first problem.
here is the link with screenshots and an explaination:
https://github.com/LucKy-4U/Firefox-Chrome-Folder

Still, if someone knows how to do it without using my stupid trick then please let me know as my trick is partially broken.

Comment: Lucky, you're welcome! Got your github repo cloned, however, didn't scrutinize it yet.  If I find out something worthy I'll come back to you here at SO.  Regards, M.

Comment: @Micha, Hi, Thanks but actually: I solved my second problem as well, worked the whole friday night on this stupid thing. :P
how do you have your firefox setup? do you use TreeStyleTabs?
I am just asking to know if you are doing all this for just me or would all that work be useful for you as well?

Comment: on github, request commit access, I would give you the permission to edit that folder. You can just update your changes over there and also upload any special changes you may have in your userchrome.css. :)) I like to see how other people modify their firefox. :))
and then post your answer here and I would accept your answer.
Sounds good?

Comment: now I need help with just one thing: what is the black line that comes below the navigation bar called?
The one that divides the navigation bar from the main_window.

Comment: Haha, no, sorry, might not be useful for me currently. So, here's to you .. ;-) I have my FF in quite boring shape, you know, some privacy & security and my convenience and dev addons, however, no chrome folder manipulations here. Just got to know the #main-window thing 1-2 months before when trying to frankenstein my Thunderbird into a Gmail clone. Just was curious, thought maybe I can help, because I know sth about window systems and also HTML & CSS. So, that's all there is to it :-) Regards, M.

Comment: hahaha, man, you are amazing. I really appreciate the work you were willing to put just to help me out. :))
But if you don't really need it then you don't have to do anything now, I figured out much of it already and my firefox is almost all sorted out. :))
now, all I need to know is the name of the black line that is right below the address_bar. that's all. I have already asked a separate question for that and have asked it on firefox support as well. :) so lets see if I get any info on it. :))

Comment: But I would like to keep in touch with you, if possible. Please add me on github or something. Maybe someday I could return the favor. :))

Comment: My pleasure!  "Please add me on github or something."  What do I do to make it happen?

Comment: well, you can just request commit access and that way we would have a way to communicate with one another on github. :))
I am not sure if it is alright to ask or allowed on github to ask for an email of the other person?

Comment: Hi, looked into that, folks present hacks here on stackoverflow to will messages to each other on github. Seems indeed there is no direct way, maybe in the past, there was, but nowadays seems its gone. So I raised an issue on your repo requesting commit access. Hope that works for us. Regards, M.